# How find support library resources using robolectric?

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm trying using robolectric to mock somethings on my android app tests. Sadly after I include a external library on my project the tests crashed.
Error info is about some library resource not found.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find any resource  from reference ResName{com.company.app:style/Theme_AppCompat_Light_NoActionBar} from style StyleData{name='AppTheme_Base', parent='Theme_AppCompat_Light_NoActionBar'} with theme null
```

Someone have this problem ?

Comment: Can you include details about the crash? You mentioned "Error info is about some library resource not found"... can you post that here too?

Comment: @MikeLaren thanks for your attention. Guilherme Torres Castro found the problem!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Libraries that contain internal resources (AKA aar) need to be mapped on project.properties files (at src/main).
The file content will be something like this (if you are using Android Studio):

```
android.library.reference.1=../app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://robolectric.org/configuring/).

Comment: This fixed the same problem I had when using AppCompat theme and ActionBarActivity with Robolectric, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This happens when Robolectric has troubles finding res directory. You can create Custom Test Runner to specify right path to res directory.

```
public class CustomTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

public CustomTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
    super(testClass);
}

@Override
protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
    final String BUILD_PATH = "src/main";
    final FileFsFile manifestFile = FileFsFile.from(BUILD_PATH, "AndroidManifest.xml");

    AndroidManifest appManifest = super.getAppManifest(config);
    return new AndroidManifest(manifestFile, appManifest.getResDirectory(), appManifest.getAssetsDirectory());
}
}
```

To use it replace:

`@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)` with: 
`RunWith(MyRobolectricTestRunner.class)` in your Robolectric tests.

In my case `appManifest.getResDirectory()` returned `"build/intermediates/res/merged/debug"`.